# Error with one to one relationship entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Good Day:

I'm trying to accomplish one to one mapping  using Entity Framework but, getting this error:

> The foreign key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type
>   'UserUpload'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the
>   model and that it is a valid primitive property.

This is my code below:

```
 public abstract class Upload 
    {
        [Key]
        [Ignore]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long   Size { get; set; }

        public UploadTypes Type { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

And my subclass:

```
   public class UserUpload : Upload
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public override Guid Id { get { return base.Id; } set { base.Id = value; } }


        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    }
```

In my abstract class, I have `[Ignore]` due to the fact that I want the property ignored by NEST (ElasticSearch dependency). I need this for Entity Framework nonetheless (my *UserUpload*).

Comment: Why are you declaring a key in the abstract class if all you are going to do is ignore it?

Comment: [Ignore] is for NEST (ElasticSearch) I was thinking this would theoretically not affect Entity Framework

Comment: You have edit things out of your question making a valid answer obsolet..

Answer (score 1):

> Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model

```
[Ignore]
[Key]
public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
```

You *HAVE* explicitly excluded it from the model.

Comment: [Ignore] is for NEST (ElasticSearch) I was thinking this would theoretically not affect Entity Framework.

Comment: [Ignore] is also used by EF to not include a property in the model.  It sounds like you are trying to re-use a data model for different purposes.  Best not to do this :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to achieve. Derived class *UserUpload* for Entity Framework and another derived class for NEST (elasticsearch).

Comment: Don't do this.  Have 2 different models.  They might /look/ the same, but in reality, there are for different purposes and therefore should be different classes.

Comment: I removed the [Ignore] from my abstract base and still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you created a new set of migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add the key configuration in the modelbuilder for that model. I found that writting there the model configuration is usually a better option.

Finally, check: 'and that it is a valid primitive property.'

Guid is not a primitive, use int instead.